# Book recommendation for studying chemistry through scientific method

Tags: experimental-chemistry, books

I really like physics and I think the reason is that I enjoy studying the process of discovering rather than reading known facts. I've tried to study chemistry but I feel introductory texts on chemistry doesn't focus on the process of discovery and how one could reach certain conclusions after following such and such thought processes. Instead they state facts.

For instance, while studying chemistry the author would tell you that a water molecule is $\mathrm{H_2O}$ (two atoms of hydrogen and one of oxygen) but doesn't explain how early scientists reached that conclusion.

Can someone recommend any introductory textbook/book that'll teach chemistry that way?

Comment: You're looking for resources on the history of science.

Comment: @Zhe Not really. Motivation and line of reasoning to reach a certain conclusion need not be how it was discovered historically.

Comment: Line of reasoning is the most recent discovery.